# Не получается добавить новую строку в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как это исправить? Хочу добавить пустую строку в конце.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   string SqlText = "SELECT * FROM [Поезд]";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlText, ConnStr);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "[Поезд]");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Поезд]"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77726/discussion-on-question-by-user297535-------datag).

Comment: @rdorn напишите ваш e-mail или скайп

Comment: я общаюсь только здесь, и только когда есть время

Comment: @rdorn мне проект сбросить вам показать

Comment: github чем не угодил?

Answer (score 0):

Как только вы положили что-то в свойство `DataSource`, включается механизм привязки данных (Binding). При включенной привязке ручное управление отображением недопустимо, о чем вам и сообщает текст ошибки.

Когда работаете с привязкой данных, менять нужно источник данных.

Один из вариантов решения:

1. Вместо локальной переменной `DataSet ds` использовать приватное поле формы например `private DataTable Trains` (у вас используется всего одна таблица), чтобы к нему был доступ из любого метода формы.
2. Заполнить поле и грид:

   ```
   string SqlText = "SELECT * FROM [Поезд]";
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlText, ConnStr);
   da.Fill(Trains);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = Trains;
   ```
3. Добавить пустую строку в `DataTable` выполнить повторную привязку данных

   ```
   Trains.Rows.Add(Trains.NewRow());
   //при необходимости выполняем повторную привязку, но обычно это лишнее
   dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = Trains;
   ```

После этого у вас появится новая строчка внизу.

---

Одно из альтернативных решений:

1. сделать модельный класс (условно `Train`) с нужными публичными свойствами.
2. Полученными из запроса данными заполнить модельные объекты.
3. Собрать полученные объекты в коллекцию `BindingList`, которую и положить в `DataGridView.DataSource`.
4. Добавлять новые незаполненные объекты в эту коллекцию.
5. Дополнительно будет полезно реализовать в модельном классе интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, он несколько облегчает работу механизму привязки и позволит автоматически отображать изменения в данных, сделанные в коде.

Вообще тема привязки данных довольно обширная и имеет массу возможных решений. как правильных, так и не очень, в зависимости от решаемой задачи.